# USB bandwidth / host controller issues - Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have 12 USB 2.0 devices plugged into an Intel NUC D54250WYK running Ubuntu 14.04.

Running `lshw -short` shows two different USB buses and two host controllers (xHCI and eHCI).

All of the USB devices appear on the same bus and use xHCI regardless of the ports they are plugged into. As a result I'm seeing the following errors in dmsg:

```
Not enough host controller resources for new device state.
Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 0.
```

Is there a way to force devices to a specific bus?

I've also read that Linux can have problems with xHCI. Is there a way to force eHCI without recompiling the kernal? Intel does not provide that option in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked on this, you're in a bit of a bind. It seems `xHCI` is compiled into the kernel, not as a module, and if you compile in `eHCI`/`aHCI`/`oHCI` and not `xHCI`, USB as a whole breaks, possibly due to some built-in support for on-board USB controlled BlueTooth and WIFI devices on certain mobos. [DO NOT UPDATE YOUR BIOS yet... see if the option to disable `xHCI` still exists on yours.](https://communities.intel.com/message/268704)

At this time, it seems your best option is to disable `xHCI` in your BIOS. This will likely disable all USB3 controllers, but allow USB2 controllers to work without this issue impeding you.

With respect to the Intel device you described, I don't see many USB ports on it, so I assume you're using hubs. From [the tech specs for your device](http://techpartner.intel.com/campaigns/documents/nuc-d54250wyk-brief.pdf), it looks like you'll have to get access to the internal header to get at the USB2 ports.

Comment: I can disable xHCI in BIOS on another machine and bring up all 12 devices successfully. I don't have this option on the Intel NUC, my target machine. I've tried a few different BIOS versions and the option is not there.

Comment: @chris_mac Then you might be ****ed, sorry. A number of people have complained about the option being disabled in newer BIOS revisions. It seems your best options are to attempt to downgrade the BIOS (if supported), or use a different device, or wait for a fix (I can't even find a bug report for this on kernel.org, sadly). If this doesn't help you, I encourage you to leave the question open for future visitors who can help more. I've tried to deal with this same issue myself, with no luck. Best of luck yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Good news for anyone else facing this issue. Intel released a new bios (v40) that adds back the option to disables xHCI. In my case I updated the bios, disabled xHCI, and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of platforms that have XHCI ONLY (Apollolake, Denverton).
You will brick your HW if you disable XHCI there.